# .html() wont show newlines in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm getting the content using `$(this).html()`, this works fine in Chrome and Firefox as I get newlines, but in IE I don't get newlines. Why is this? I need newlines for markdown to work.

This is how it looks in the db (using MySQL Workbench):

[image]

This is how it looks like when I alert the content from `$(this).html()` in...

... Chrome:

[image]

... IE(8):

[image]

I tried outputting it in the console but same thing there, newlines in Chrome but not in IE(8). How can I get newlines with IE?

I fetch data (with ajax) and put it in a div and then loop all new entries in that div and converts it to markdown.

Answer (score 1):

IE normally uses `\r\n` for newlines, try that instead of just `\n` !

Also, jQuery states the following : Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned from html() may vary in newlines and other white space.

jQuery text() is often a better option for escaped characters, and sometimes even double escaping will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0260__Dialogs/StartanewlineinalertboxinIE.htm) a `\r` should work.

And according to [this link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40785) a `\n` should work

Have you tried both options?

Have you considered a [jQuery modal popup (dialog)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)? then you have more style options and cross browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

`\n` Should work you can check for the User agent if it is Chrome or Mozilla try using Jquery Flash or