# IE7 stripping newlines when placing info from a DIV into a TEXTAREA

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to fetch HTML/Text from a DIV and place it as-is (newlines and all) in a textarea. Seems simple enough, however IE7 is deciding to strip the newlines.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qU29k/1/ - it should work correct on other browsers but IE7 will place all the text on a single line. This happens when using both .html() and .text(). I've also tried replacing \n's with \r\n's as per: [.html() wont show newlines in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502126/html-wont-show-newlines-in-ie) but that was a no-go either.

Any ideas how this can be remedied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by changing the div to a textarea.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qU29k/7/